# Opacity for paragraph

Tags: html

I am setting opacity of my paragraph similar to this site, but when I've used opacity 0.1 on my div the text is also getting an opacity of 1, i've set two divs but still isn't the same as this site http://www.infosys.com/about/Pages/index.aspx. My http://jsfiddle.net/5v3p7/.

```
Here is my html:
<!DOCTYPE.html>

</html>

<div id="center">

<div id="content">


<div id="text">
Building Tomorrow’s Enterprise

Infosys is a global leader in consulting, technology and outsourcing solutions. As a proven partner focused on building tomorrow's enterprise, Infosys enables clients in more than 30 countries to outperform the competition and stay ahead of the innovation curve. With US$8.095bn in LTM Q3 FY14 revenues and 158,000+ employees, Infosys provides enterprises with strategic insights on what lies ahead. We help enterprises transform and thrive in a changing world through strategic consulting, operational leadership and the co-creation of breakthrough solutions, including those in mobility, sustainability, big data and cloud computing.

Learn more about how Infosys is Building Tomorrow’s Enterprise
Learn more about industry solutions from Infosys.
Learn more about services from Infosys
Learn more about products from Infosys

</div>


</div>

</div>

<div id="img">

<img src="http://hoklife.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/02/office-1.jpg">
</div>


Here is my css:
html
{
background:blue;
}
#content
{
position:relative;
z-index:1;
background:black;
color:silver;
min-height:1000px;
opacity:0.5;
font-size:40px;
width:960px;
margin-right:auto;
margin-left:auto;
padding:20px;
}
#text
{
position:relative;
z-index:3;
color:white;
min-height:500px;
opacity:10;
width:500px;
font-size:40px;
}
#img
{
position:fixed;
top:-50%;
left:-50%;
height:200%;
width:200%;
}
#img img
{
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
right:0;
bottom:0;
margin:auto;
min-height:50%;
min-width:50%;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use background with rgba, like this:-

```
#content {
position: relative;
z-index: 1;
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
color: silver;
min-height: 1000px;
font-size: 40px;
width: 960px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
padding: 20px;
}
```